# In JavaScript is there a difference between referencing an object's variable name vs. using `this` when declaring new key:value pairs of the object?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript is there a difference between referencing a object's variable name vs. using `this` when declaring new key:value pairs of the object?

```
    var foo = {
      bar: function() {
        foo.qux = 'value';
      }
    };

    alert(foo.qux); // undefined
    foo.bar();
    alert(foo.qux); // 'value'

    var foo = {
      bar: function() {
        this.qux = 'value';
      }
    };

    alert(foo.qux); // undefined
    foo.bar();
    alert(foo.qux); // value
```

Also: http://jsbin.com/emayub/9/edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just considering the presented code, both will do the same. But there are some things to keep in mind:

`foo` is not the **name** of the object it is the name of the **variable**.

And variables can change. Consider this:

```
var bar = foo;
foo = null;
```

Using `foo` would break the code code, but when using `this`, `bar.bar()` will still work as expected.

By using `foo`, you are making the function dependent on the name of variable, so whenever the variable changes, the function breaks. This is also an important aspect regarding code refactoring.

Comment: Appreciate the first sentence as this was an oversimplified example.  When I think this pattern of using the object variable name can be useful is from a organizational and code readability perspective specifically when you are working with a global object that will not have it's variable name changed, and your application utilizes a good amount of event driven logic.  I could definitely be advocating worst practices - but its just a thought.